# Observer to get notification for clear notifications in notification center

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, badge

I am trying to manage badge on my iOS application. The badge is increased when new push notification is received and decreased when user has tapped on a notification from notification centre.

The problem is that when the user clears all notifications from the notification centre using clear button, all notifications are cleared (not an issue), but badge gets decreased only when the user taps on notification. Which creates count stack of cleared notification.

One solution might be to set an observer that can send a notification through notification centre to my application and badge count can be set to 0. I was unable to find observer for that.

Any help other than observer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think the badge count can not be set when your app is not in active state, You can take a look for the default message App in iOS. It only get set to ZERO when you open the App.

Comment: @Janmenjaya raised a valid point here. On the other hand, you can't get the notification count those are shown in notification centre as well as you can't get any notification when user clears all the notifications from notification centre. So basically it's not possible. All you can do is, just mark your application badge to 0 when your application become active.